# Euler's totient function counts

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, number-theory

Let $n$ be a positive integers. Euler's totient function counts the positive integers up to a given integer n that are relatively prime to n. It is written using the Greek letter phi as $\phi(n)$. Put 
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}‎
‎1&0&0&\cdots & 1\\‎
‎1&1&0&\cdots & 2\\‎
1&0&1&\cdots & 3\\‎
‎\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\‎
‎‎\end{bmatrix}$$
$A$ is the $n\times n$ matrix where the last columns of matrix $A$ are the numbers $1,2,3,\ldots$ and the others entries of the columns  $A=(a_{i,p})$ where $1\leq i,p \leq n$ is defined as following
$$
‎a_{i,p} =
    \begin{cases}
            1, &         \text{if } p\mid i,\\
            0, &         \text{if } p\nmid i.
    \end{cases}$$
Proved that $\phi(n)=\mid A\mid$.

Comment: What's $p$?  When do you think $i\nmid i$?

Comment: What is your question exactly? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Florian I closed to prove it! By using multiplicative of ϕ(n) it is enough to prove for ‎$‎n=p^k‎$‎. The entry of ‎rows ‎‎$‎p^{k−1}‎$‎ and ‎$‎p^k‎$‎ are equal but the entries ‎$‎a_{p^{k-1},n}‎‎=p^{k−1}‎$‎ and ‎$‎a_{p^k,n}‎‎=p^k‎$‎.So by subtracting these two rows we have $\phi(p^k)=p^k-p^{k-1}$